# Read and parse file, on server or client side?

Tags: javascript, file-io, client-server, server-side

My question is simple: **Should I read and parse the file on server or client side?**

I just want to validate and then show that data in `html format`.

If I do it on the client side, I would like to read any `spreadsheet document`, `csv` or `xml` data file and i want to know if there are libraries for JavaScript to make it happen (I googled some options, but i believe some of you can suggest libraries that you have already used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to read files via JavaScript within a browser, then you cannot do that as [sand-boxing](http://www.howtogeek.com/169139/sandboxes-explained-how-theyre-already-protecting-you-and-how-to-sandbox-any-program/) will prevent you to do that for known security reasons. You are left with the server side where many options are available to process any kind of file.

**[EDIT]**
Although HTML5 provides an API to manipulate files, browser support not being complete across the different browsers, the viable option is to stick to server side processing.

Comment: See the HTML5 File API.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks for pointing this out. Assuming the user browser supports HTML5, HTML can be validated using the DOM.

Comment: How much i lose in speed if i send the file to server and after that return it to the client, instead of doing all that in client side?
Lets say about 1mb data, what would be the difference?

Comment: yeah, i meant older versions like 8 and 9 which still build good percentage of usage as this one says: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: @JovanMeshkov Simple arithmetics. With 512Kb upstream, a one MB file would roughly upload within 1,000,000x8/512/1024=15 seconds.

Comment: Alright, thank you for all the answers, i guess server side is the option

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library (not on my Git sorry) that does what you appear to be wanting to do with an xml doc.

The steps are to use the js file to load an xml file via AJAX.  Once you've fetched the data, create a variable that contains the xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Tag names");  Scrutinising via else if statements will let you look at the nodes of the xml file and write to the DOM based on what each node contains.

eg:

```
else if (this.node === 'Text_box'){
$(".div").append("<input>blah</input");
return;
}

else if (this.node === 'Image'){
$(".div").append("<img>blah</img>");
return;
}
```

etc etc.  I just spammed that out quite quickly and I'm not even 100% sure if that's what you're trying to do.  There's performance costs associated with doing it via the client-side, but there's server bandwidth gains too if you're relying on CDN's.  http://nicollet.net/2012/07/html-rendering-client-or-server - discusses the pro and cons of going server/client.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but i decided to do it server side